# UIRefreshControl for "Pull Up" to refresh?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uirefreshcontrol

How do I add UIRefreshControl to bottom of a UIColloectionView? That means how does it work when It comes to Scroll up (to see old data or something)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [CCBottomRefreshControl](https://github.com/vlasov/CCBottomRefreshControl) category for UIScrollView class (parent of UICollectionView class) that implements **bottomRefreshControl** property. It's compatible with both iOS 6 and 7 native refresh controls.

Answer (score 12):

You can't use `UIRefreshControl` to do that, but if you're ok with a simpler solution, you could just set up your collection view to automatically load more data when you scroll to the bottom. (Incidentally, this is a far more common user interface ... the pull up to refresh is not common, but automatically retrieving more data when you hit the bottom is.)

The most primitive rendition of that would be to respond to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method and determine if you've scrolled to the bottom of the collection view (which is, itself, a subclass of the `UIScrollView`):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        if (!self.isLoadingMoreData)
        {
            self.loadingMoreData = YES;

            // proceed with the loading of more data
        }
    }
}
```

Even better, if you have more data to load, show a cell at the bottom, that says "please wait, loading more data", perhaps with a `UIActivityIndicatorView`. For example, if you have more data to load, add a section to the end with this one cell. If you format this additional cell properly (e.g. a single cell that goes all the way across the collection view), it could definitely render the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Do you have a sample code for giving user this notification? I load data when scrolling to end and everything works fine. Now i just need the notification when data is loading. Not that simple to load an extra cell for doing this notification. Thanks!

Comment: @S.Birklin - I think it's easier than you suspect. Just have your `numberOfRowsForSection` return one extra row (assuming you have extra data to fetch). Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` can just see if it's gone beyond it's range of existing data and show the "loading" cell if that's the case. See https://github.com/robertmryan/UITableView-Bottom-Refresh for simplistic illustration.

Comment: I have decided to use the approach you used in your github example. There is one part i am unsure of. How should the tableView respond when the server says: we have no more data for you? I was trying to get the tableView to remove the loading cell, but was getting error while removing the cell. Any ideas? or should i ask a new question..

Comment: well removing code is a one line of code --> `rableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([myIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)`   The error that i get is --> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (14) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (14), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section. It looks as if the row is not being removed. I am now looking to see if this is because the delegate method is returning an extra count object --> numberOfRowsInSection {return sellerData.count + 1}

Comment: Correct. When you call `deleteRows...`, it will call `numberOfRows...` which must now return one less than it did before.

Answer (score -3):

You can't. You can't really customise `UIRefreshControl` at all.