# UIrefresh Control on UIcollectionView at the top and bottom

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, paging, uirefreshcontrol

I want to add paging in my collectionView. I am using Waterfall layout in my collection View. Having two rows only.

Scrolling is horizontal. I want to add paging in such a way that user can go back and forth the pages.

I found one of that over Git by Simon Westerlund. But in this UIrefreshCOntrol is added at the top only. I want to ahev UIrefresh control at the bottom too. So that I can show paging Effect. Just as, its in the case of Facebook app

Comment: Please see the below thread regarding your question as It already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915018/uirefreshcontrol-for-pull-up-to-refresh

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use bounce effect of `UICollectionView` coz its already inherited from `UIScrollView` and use following delegate method

You just have to add following lines and call your method instead of `[self fetchMoreEnteries]`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"Scroll End Called");
        [self fetchMoreEntries];
    }
 }
```

Comment: but i don't think you should add pull to refresh at bottom because at bottom we have to add buttons for loading more entries but pull to refresh is used to reload all exist data. I think you can add only indicator view.

Comment: but the above logic is not correct. even if i scroll small, this method gets called

Comment: no not working. If my collectionview is of same size as the content, the delegate is called again which I donot need,

Comment: can you please explain in detail what is currently happening and what is your expectation?