# how to implement Refresh control in the bottom of the tableview?

Tags: ios

In the tableView , when I am pulling down from the top, it is fetching the data. But if I want pulling up the data from the bottom in tableView, how can I implement a refresh Control in tableview, please suggest me

Comment: You need to configure that yourself.. Using `UIScrollViewDelegate` or use external libraries, like what @David is suggesting..

Comment: Please see the below thread regarding your question as It already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915018/uirefreshcontrol-for-pull-up-to-refresh

Answer (score 2):

[Try this](https://github.com/emenegro/bottom-pull-to-refresh), Very easy to implement.